# systemd-resolved not cache not effective when queries from haproxy

Tags: domain-name-system, haproxy, cache, systemd

We're running HAProxy 1.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 and we've been noticing slow startup times. We've previously pinned slow startups on DNS lookups, since we have lots of backends which HAProxy has to resolve at startup.

However, since the server is running `systemd-resolved` with caching enabled, this should not be an issue (most of the backends are using the same host). We have confirmed that `systemd-resolved` is in fact running and cache is enabled by trying some `dig` commands and looking at the network traffic.

But when HAProxy starts, we see lots of outbound DNS lookup traffic, even though those queries should be cached. This is also confirmed by `systemd-resolved` `stats` which show thousands of cache misses.

Switching to `dnsmasq` instead of `systemd-resolved` makes the system behave as expected - the first few DNS lookups are not cached, but everything after them is cached and HAProxy startup is fast.

The question is: What could cause `systemd-resolved` to not cache DNS queries, and why does it only happen with HAProxy queries, and not when using `dig`?

Comment: Did you find out what happened?

Comment: @Benni unfortunately not. We're still using dnsmasq. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: Similar problems - it turns out that on ubuntu20 systemd-resolved's default value appears to be 'yes', but it is not, it caches everything once you explicitly set it to 'yes'